# Elasticsearch stopped working suddenly

Tags: ubuntu, vps, java, elasticsearch

I have deployed Elasticsearch on a development Ubuntu VPS. 
We use that VPS only to host API for mobile apps.

Everything worked good till today, elasticsearch stopped working.

I tried to restart it, it says "Server ok" but when I check the status it gives me: "is not running".

The Ruby on Rails app log contains:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))
```

After that, I start getting this error: `Too many open files`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Too many open files

/etc/security/limits.d/elasticsearch.conf

```
elasticsearch soft nofile 32000
elasticsearch hard nofile 32000
```

The look at your init script for the ulimit setting and raise it.

```
if [ -n "$MAX_OPEN_FILES" ]; then
    ulimit -n $MAX_OPEN_FILES
fi
```

On my ubuntu server, I also had to edit /etc/defaults/elasticsearch.

See generally:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/too-many-open-files/

Comment: /etc/security/limits.d/ does not contains the file elasticsearch.conf
Should i create it ?

Comment: Do you mean /etc/security/limits ?

Comment: No. The limits.d/*.conf files are read in as stub files.